# System.NotSupportedException: 'ConfigureServices returning an System.IServiceProvider isn't supported.' with Structure Map

Tags: c#, structuremap, .net-core-3.0

I am trying to inject the structure map into .net core 3.0 web API but Continuously I am getting the error in my Program.cs class. I haven't found any solution related to the structure map, everyone discussing Autofac

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });

    }
```

my Startup class is

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();

            var container = new Container();
            container.Configure(config =>
            {
                config.AddRegistry(new CustomRegistry());
                config.Populate(services);
            });

            return container.GetInstance<IServiceProvider>();
        }


        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.
Thanks for the Help in the advance!!

Comment: `StructureMap` is sunsetted, you need to either move to `Lamar` or even better yet `Autofac` more info https://github.com/structuremap/StructureMap.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

Comment: @HariHaran thanks for the link and found the solution myself.

Answer (score 1):

Program.cs add AutofacServiceProviderFactory like under code

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        }).UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());
```

then add ConfigureContainer in StartUp.cs

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Program).Assembly).
        Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("service", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).AsImplementedInterfaces();
            builder.RegisterDynamicProxy();

}
```

in dotnet core 3.0 change ioc way

Answer (score 0):

StructureMap can be configured in ASP.NET Core 7.0 with the following in `Program.cs`

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(new StructureMapServiceProviderFactory(new Registry()))
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

And below method in `Startup.cs`

```cs
public void ConfigureContainer(Registry registry)
{
    registry.IncludeRegistry<FooRegistry>();
}
```

Found the AutoFac documentation on [ASP.NET Core 3.0+ and Generic Hosting](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting) helpful in arriving at the solution.